# Smarty Calculation with Database Value

Tags: php, mysql, math, smarty

I am trying to make a calculation based on the database value.Basically I am displaying some data by following code in my `tpl` file

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"> 

{foreach from=$data item=item key=key} 

  <tr> 
      <td>{$item.Country}</td> <td>{$item.count}</td> <td>{$item.sum}</td> 
  <tr> 

 {/foreach} 

</table>
```

Now I need to make a calculation based on `{$item.count}` and `{$item.sum}` By searching I am finding below `smarty math calculation formula`

```
{* $height=4, $width=5 *}
{math equation="x + y" x=$height y=$width}
```

But can not assign my database variable.How can I do this

Comment: Did you also read the "warning" in the manual? "{math} is an expensive function in performance due to its use of the php eval() function. Doing the math in PHP is much more efficient"

Comment: Can't you just simply do `{math equation="x + y" x=$item.count y=$item.sum}` by the way Or if that does not work something like `{assign var="x" value=$item.count} {assign var="y" value=$item.sum} {math equation="x + y" x=$x y=$y}`

Comment: tried but not displaying any results nor showing any error

Comment: "tried but not displaying any results nor showing any error " Questions on stackoverflow should also include tryed code... Besides is error_reporting and display_errors active on the server?

Comment: no i mean i tried your code given in your comments

Comment: "no i mean i tried your code given in your comments" Ok nevermind then, i misunderstood that other comment

Comment: its alright thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can do basic math without the math function.

```
{assign var=x value=12}
{assign var=y value=4}
{assign var=sum value=$x+$y}
{assign var=difference value=$x-$y}
{assign var=product value=$x*$y}
{assign var=quotient value=$x/$y}
{assign var=modulo value=$x/$y}
{assign var=operations value=(($x/$y)*($x-$y)*9)-1}
<p>{$x} + {$y} = {$sum}</p>
<p>{$x} - {$y} = {$difference}</p>
<p>{$x} * {$y} = {$product}</p>
<p>{$x} / {$y} = {$quotient}</p>
<p>{$x} % {$y} = {$modulo}</p>
<p>(({$x}/{$y})*({$x}-{$y})*9)-1 = {$operations}</p>
```

[image: Smarty results]